# Chrome returns null when using getElementById() in the console until I inspect an element?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, console

I use CTRL+SHIFT+I to open the JS Console on a page I am working on (not one I am actively developing) in Chrome Version 86.0.4240.111, I immediately start to type `document.getElementById('Clear All')` and I get back `null`

But after I click the `Elements` tab, and inspect the element with the `id="Clear All"` attribute, running the same function (`document.getElementById('Clear All')`) returns the element.

Does this have something to do with there being a space in the `id` attribute?  Is there a way to preload the DOM so that I can pull the `Clear All` element without inspecting the page first?

Additionally of note, this page has `<frameset>`s and the element I want to access is inside one.

Considering this is a newer product, I really can't believe they use `<frameset>`s.

Comment: you cant use id with space like 'Clear All'

Comment: You could try `'Clear\ All'` or `'Clear\\ All'` and see if that would escape the space

Comment: @BahadorRaghibizadeh I wish I had a choice in the matter, it's not mine to modify.

Comment: @Taplar That did not work, but thank you.

Comment: Also the element I'm trying to access is in a `<frameset>`...does that help?

Comment: Figured it out, the issue was that everything was buried in a nested, nested frameset.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use space on ID ... try id="clear-all" on element and on javascript->  document.getElementById("clear-all")